# Calling .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that has rows of data:

```
<tbody>                       
   <tr class="rows">
     <td><input type="text" name="total" value="3500.00" id="total" class="price"></td>
     <td>$<input type="text" value="23.00" name="customerS" id="customerS" class=""></td>
   </tr>

  <tr class="rows">
     <td><input type="text" name="total" value="3900.00" id="total" class="price"></td>
     <td>$<input type="text" value="3446.00" name="customerS" id="customerS" class=""></td>
  </tr>                            
</tbody>
```

I want to call a function using Ids of the rows.

```
format('total', 'customerS');
```

What I cant figure out is how to call the function format using `.each` so that format is called for each tr(rows). Please let me know, Thanks.

Comment: you can not use same id on element.

Comment: i dont understand people down voting this question he is new and
wanted to ask a question why down vote?

Comment: @Liran This site is full of wannabe script kiddies that downvote without explaining, purely because they don't understand enough to justify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just chain `each()`:

```
$('tr.rows').each(function(){
    format('total', 'customers');
});
```

Though if the arguments should be variables, dependant on some property of the `tr` element, then you'd need to provide more details.

It's worth noting, however, that you're duplicating `id`s in the elements contained within the `tr`s, which is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(".rows").each(function(element){
var curretnRow = $(element);    
// apply your function here
});
```

`$(".rows")` => this will get all the TRs with the class name "Row".

`.each(function(element){}` => this will iterate over each element in the collection, giving you a reference to the current element in the 'element' variable.

**Note:** I can see that each TR has element that holds the same ID, this is not the correct way when dealing with repeated elements. 
I think dealing with class names and trying to have unique IDs for each element should be your first step in order to have a maintain-able code.

I wish it's now more clear for you, let me know if this has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should not use the same id for more than one element. You can use class instead.

```
      <tbody>                       
             <tr class="rows">
                 <td><input type="text" name="total" value="3500.00" id="total"   class="price">
                 </td>
                 <td>$<input type="text" value="23.00" name="customerS" class="customerS" class=""></td>
             </tr>

             <tr class="rows">
                 <td><input type="text" name="total" value="3900.00" id="total"   class="price">
                 </td>
                 <td>$<input type="text" value="3446.00" name="customerS" class="customerS" class=""></td>
             </tr>                            
                </tbody>
```

And then

```
jQuery(".customerS").each(function(index, element) {
    blah blah...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').each(function() {...code...});
```